# V8 debugger in Eclipse: Logic, or weirdest bug ever?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, v8, javascript-debugger

I am writing a **Node.js** application in which I fill an **Object** with data using string-turned-integers as keys (e.g. "62616324573"). Objects always store keys **{key:}** as Strings, which is ideal compared to the way javascript **arrays** and their **[index]** work:

An array defines a million times `undefined`, once for every index between defined indices.

However, I found that I cannot debug my new objects properly because the `Variables` panel in `Eclipse` displays `Failed to read variables`. Internally they seem to work fine.

Take the following code:

```
var util = require('util');
util.debug('Run this with --debug-brk=port, and press Resume (F8) to break at the breakpoint below.');

var debugMe = {
    "1000000000" : {
//  "2011743958" : {
        "some" : 1234,
        "random" : true,
        "data" : undefined
    },
//  "1000000001" : {
//  "8302611133" : {
    "3302611133" : {
        "some" : 12345678,
        "random" : false,
        "data" : null
    }
};

util.debug(JSON.stringify(debugMe)); // Look, it prints fine in all cases. This is internal javascript code.
util.debug('...');
util.inspect(debugMe); // And now it doesn't. This is V8 debugging code.

var breakpoint_here = true; // Set breakpoint here!

// hohoho
```

Set a breakpoint at `breakpoint_here` and run this with instant-break debugger, e.g. `node --debug-brk=5858 debugtest.js`. Press `resume` to jump from line 1 to the breakpoint. Go to your `Variables` panel and try to inspect `debugMe`: the panel will crash.

Try again with 10..00 and 10..01. No problem. Except, the numbers appear to be parsed as an array index (!) judging by the way it is written.

```
debugMe ->
  [1000000000] -> [Object]
  [1000000001] -> [Object]
```

Now try the 10..10 and 83..02. Suddenly, 83..33 is a normal `JSON key` instead of an array index, but 10..00 is still an array index. (?)

```
debugMe ->
  8302611133 ->  [Object]
  [1000000000] -> [Object]
```

Now try 10..00 and 33..33, and the `Variables` window will crash again. This is what I expected:

```
debugMe ->
  1000000000 -> [Object]
  3302611133 -> [Object]
```

This is what I am **guessing** is happening, although you can't actually see it when debugging an object that still cooperates:

```
debugMe ->
  [1000000000] -> [Object]
  [1000000001] -> undefined
  // (...) // debugger memory fills up
  [3302611132] -> undefined
  [3302611133] -> [Object]
```

The problem I am guessing is that the numbers in this case are both array indices and the difference is too large, because the debugger will remember 2302611133 times `undefined`, a problem that should only exist when `array` is used in stead of JSON `object`.

- Why are some numbers taken as key (string) and others taken as index?
- Why do some combination of indices work in the debugger, and others don't?
- Is the "million times undefined" problem without me knowing also happening with objects?

Let me recap:

- Small differences in string-cast integers 'int' seem to work fine, but in the debugger they become [indices]
- Big differences up to about a billion in the key don't work, `Variables` window crashes. No console output.
- Even bigger differences work again, but some become [index] and others stay 'key'.

Because I had to do manual crashtests, it has taken me forever to find out the problem was in the numbers, and not the contents of the objects themselves. It's hard to imagine the problem affects only the debugger and not the application itself, because it's the same (V8) engine. I'm hoping someone can point out all the facts and variables I am missing.

-update-

No one seems to know about this. Not known logic, nor a known bug. I [filed a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388346) at Eclipse WDT, although I am not sure that's the source of the behavior.

Comment: Object keys are Strings, not Numbers. That you see V8 sometimes converting them to Strings for use as keys suggests it uses heuristics to decide whether it's best to use the Number as a index in an Array or convert it to a String for use as a key in an Object. Have you tried converting the Numbers to Strings *before* using them? That should force V8 to use an Object... I have no idea what is wrong with Eclipse though.

Comment: I am using the double quote syntax ("1000000000") which implies (String). The above example is all you need to recreate this behavior, there is no extra step where I use (Int) instead of (String).

Comment: Like you say, Object keys are Strings. You inspired me to think that the debugger mistakingly parses strings as numbers, but only on certain values. As if there is a magic number, like 65535 used to be on MSX-Basic, above which the integer-parsing does not happen anymore.

Comment: Sorry I was focusing on your debug output rather than your code which led me to the premise that it was something to do with Integers as Strings. One other point to note: inspect is part of NodeJS, not V8.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate you thinking with me. As for your other point, NodeJS is built upon the V8 javascript engine, and the debugger is provided by the V8 Chrome Developer Tools (for Eclipse). So I think the problem is with either V8 and/or Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asker here,

Short:
**It's a bug**. Use `potatoesalad` as a workaround. (see other answer)

Longer:

The lack of response makes me believe there is no logic, and this is in fact a bug.

At first, I was unclear to the source of the bug (Eclipse/WDT/Node/V8), so I filed a [bugreport at Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388346).

The bug turned out to be `not_eclipse`, so I [re-filed the bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=75) at the Chrome Dev Tools project.

This bug was accepted, and turned out to be two bugs:
[Issue 76](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=76), and
[Issue 77](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=77).

Answer (score 0):

Although it can introduce a lot of little rewrites when your node application uses a lot of integer-based lookups, the **easiest workaround** is to introduce `potatoesalad` to your code.

e.g.

```
var debugMe = {
    "potatoesalad1000000000" : {},
    "potatoesalad3302611133" : {}
};
```

Now the debugger works as expected and you can at least debug your program while we're waiting for someone knowledgeable to explain this phenomenon.